# appengine - custom domain

Tags: dns

I configured my appengine app with my domain www.mydomain.com.co, but it doesnt works just with mydomain.com.co (without subdomain).

There is a restriction?
What could be wrong?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can´t be configured like this.

Some domain providers, like godaddy in my case, allow to redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com